# Output cell every nth row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I output a cell's value every nth rows

Example every 3 rows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in `A2`:

```
=ArrayFormula(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(C2:C4&"♦︎",3),"♦︎")))
```

Answer (score 2):

or you can do it with `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY(A2:A, "skipping 3")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `MOD`:

```
=FILTER(A2:A, MOD(ROW(A2:A)-2, 3)=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I want to do the opposite. I have the values in col B and I want to spill them in col A every nth row - if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Offset is relatively simple. To get an index that increases by 1 every three rows just ROUNDDOWN the ROW address by three

```
=OFFSET($C$2,ROUNDDOWN(ROW(A1),0)/3,0)
```